# Changing the video frame quality(compress) in to JPEG and rendering

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, video-streaming

I'm totally new to OpenCv library and I'm implementing a simple client server application using Opencv and python. Here the client captures the video from the webcam and sends it to the server. I need to compress the video frame in order to reduce the bandwidth usage. As I could find we can save the frame in to a JPEG which is a loosy compression a technique. But using the provided method I have to write the frame into and JPEG image. What I need is without writing to an image rendering the low quality(compressed frame). What i'm currently doing is writing to a JPEG and reading it again. two IO cycles per a single frame is not efficient at all. Can anyone suggest a better solution?

```
cv2.imwrite('imageName.jpg', frame, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 90])
newFrame=cv2.imread('imageName.jpg')
cv2.imshow('preview',newFrame);
```

(frame= current image frame I captured, 
 newFrame=loading the saved image in to the programme)

Comment: If you [read the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imdecode), you may notice there are two functions named `imencode` and `imdecode`...

Comment: @DanMašek Tha nk you very much.It was useful!